# Unique Linear Combination of Integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let's consider two natural numbers $M,N\in\mathbb{N}$, they can be either coprime or not. Let's also consider all their integer-coefficient linear combinations of the type $u(k,l)=kM+lN$, with $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ taking all the values in a limited discrete set $\mathbf{A}=\{-W,..0,..,W\}$, containing all the integers from $-W$ to $W$, with $W\in \mathbb{N}$.

My question is: for which conditions on $M$,$N$ and $W$ all the linear combinations will be distinct (i.e. $u(k,l)$ is injective in $\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{A}$)?

An extension. Let's say $M$ and $W$ are given. What is a smart and fast way to find a value of $N$ that satisfies the uniqueness condition stated before?

I tried to look for the Bézout's Identity and Frobenius coin kind of things but to no success (at the moment).

Edit: Added some clarifications.

A quick example. $M=2$, $N=3$, $W=3$.

$-3\times M+2\times N=0$ but also $0\times M+0\times N=0$. In this case there are two ways to obtain the same linear combination (i.e. $0$).

Comment: Does the set $\mathbf{A}$ consist of all the integers from $-W$ to $W$?

Answer (score 1):

The condition is $|2W|< \frac{\max(M,N)}{\gcd(M,N)}$

This is necessary because $WN -WM=(W-\frac{M}{\gcd(M,N)})N-(W-\frac{N}{\gcd(M,N)})M$

It is sufficient because if $k_1M+l_1M = k_2M+l_2N$ then $k_1-k_2$ is a multiple of $\frac{N}{\gcd(N,M)}$ and $l_1-l_2$ is a multiple of $\frac{M}{\gcd(N,M)}$. So if $l_1\neq l_2$ and $k_1\neq k_2$ we must have that one of $l_1-l_2$ and $k_1-k_2$ is greater than $2l$.